# increase displayed link limit in graphdb workbench?

Tags: graphdb

In the GraphDB Workbench web interface under "Visual Graph" "Settings", there is an option to change the maximum number of edges to show in the graph that maxes out at 1000. Is it possible to change (increase) that limit somewhere in a config file?

I'm using GraphDB 9.4 free edition.

Thanks!